# it is possible to pass argument to powershell script a datatable?

Tags: powershell, power-automate-desktop

I'm trying to create a PowerShell script that inserts a datatable to SQL via WriteToServer...
This script is called by a PowerAutomateDesktop automation.
So... I cannot pass my datatable as an argument :(
%dt% it s datatable variable which needs to be used inside powershell script.
This is my dilemma - it is interpreted as a string or something like that

```
#Invoke-sqlcmd Connection string parameters
$params = @{'server'='SQLEXPRESS';'Database'='Db'}
 
Write-Output %dt%

#Variable to hold output as data-table
$dataTable = %dt% |  Out-DataTable
#Define Connection string
$connectionString = "Data Source=DSQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Db"
 
#Bulk copy object instantiation
$bulkCopy = new-object ("Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy") $connectionString
#Define the destination table 
$bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.__SALES"
#load the data into the target
$bulkCopy.WriteToServer($dataTable)
#Query the target table to see for output
Invoke-Sqlcmd @params -Query "SELECT  * FROM dbo.__SALES" | format-table -AutoSize
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

No loner need to pass an argument - I create the datatable inside the script.
Thanks again!

Comment: Where's `%dt%` coming from? If it's a variable, it should be `$dt` if anything

Comment: yep - my bad. the %dt% is acting like an argument for the powershell script. 
It's a datatable variable inside powerautomatedesktop and needs to be used inside the ps script

Answer (score 0):

Work-around: create the datatable inside the script